# Missing CGI Web-Role template in Azure Toolkit 1.4; how to run PHP now?

Tags: php, .net, wordpress, azure, fastcgi

I was about to deploy WordPress on Microsoft Azure Cloud following this excellent blog:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windows-azure-support/archive/2010/08/10/microsoft-cloud-computing-windows-azure-host-wordpress-on-windows-azure-using-sql-azure-and-windows-azure-storage-run-php-application-in-windows-azure.aspx

It all worked very well until step 2/3, when I had to add the CGI Web Role project template.  Unfortunately since the new August Azure Toolkit 1.4 this template is not included anymore.

It is not very clear how an alternative approach would solve the lack of that template. 
Is here any pro who could help me running PHP on Azure toolkit 1.4 or greater?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[acknowledging that this post is almost a year old]

This has been made SUPER EASY with the Windows Azure Websites feature - see http://chriskoenig.net/2012/06/08/windows-azure-web-sites/ for more information on how to get started with a WordPress site on Windows Azure.

Basically what you can do now is use the Application Gallery that's a part of the Windows Azure Websites feature to automatically  provision a Windows Azure Website and a corresponding MYSQL Database, and then deploy your choice of open source application to that website. My sample walks through using WordPress, but there are many others to choose from.

Answer (score 1):

If you need the flexibility of Azure Cloud Services over Azure Websites (as I did), there is a post [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/bdf2fee8-58fc-4312-b6c9-0a2af95a2952/cgi-web-role-with-visual-studio-tools-for-azure-14-august-update) on the Windows Azure forums which mentions that...

- creating a general/traditional web role,
- creating a Web.roleconfig file and
- deleting the "Sites" element from the service definition file (ServiceDefinition.csdef)

...will turn the web role into a CGI web role.

However, I didn't go down this route as I wasn't sure what should be included in the Web.roleconfig file. Instead I used the *Windows Azure PowerShell* (part of the [Windows Azure SDK for PHP](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/php/common-tasks/download-php-sdk/)) to...

- [create a local Cloud Services project](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/php/common-tasks/create-web-and-worker-roles/#header-3) using `New-AzureServiceProject projectName`
- [add a PHP Web Role](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/php/common-tasks/create-web-and-worker-roles/#header-4) using `Add-AzurePHPWebRole roleName`
- [download publishing settings](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/php/how-to-guides/powershell-cmdlets/#ImportPubSettings) using `Get-AzurePublishSettingsFile`
- [import publishing settings](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/php/how-to-guides/powershell-cmdlets/#ImportPubSettings) using `Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile filePathAndName`
- [deploy a Cloud Service to Azure](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/php/how-to-guides/powershell-cmdlets/#Deploy) using `Publish-AzureServiceProject`

<sup>Note: you may need to scroll up a little on some of the above links as
the relevant text is often just above the viewport!</sup>

Without writing any PHP code, I was then able to open the Site URL for the Cloud Service and a PHP configuration page was shown. This is because an "index.php" file containing a call to `phpinfo()` is created when adding a PHP Web Role.

I was also surprised how easy it was to make a Remote Desktop connection to the running Cloud Service instance by...

- calling `Enable-AzureServiceProjectRemoteDesktop` and entering a username and password to use for the Remote Desktop connection
- (re)deploying the project using `Publish-AzureServiceProject`
- logging into the [management portal](https://manage.windowsazure.com)
- clicking **INSTANCES** on my Cloud Service's dashboard
- selecting the appropriate instance
- clicking **CONNECT** at the bottom to download an RDP file
- launching the RDP file and entering the username and password I specified above

I hope that helps!